# Can't view full-text catalogs in SQL Server 2008 with Advanced Services

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I'm using SQL Server 2008 with Advanced Services on my Vista Home Premium. I'd installed Full-text searching during installation, The SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher is running thorough an admin user account. When I go to a database through the SQL Server Management Studio, I don't see the "Storage" option under the database, so I can't create/edit my Full-text catalogs.

I was able to create a Full-text catalog through T-SQL, and can run Full-text searches on the columns I've selected in the database. I'm just not able to see the "Storage" option.

Any idea what's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the answer is:

SQL Management Studio Basic doesn't support Full-text catalogs. Catalogs can only be created via T-SQL. [This is a feature that might be added in the future](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3912985&SiteID=1).

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
EXEC sp_fulltext_database 'enable';
GO
```

Then,

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ftcatalog;
GO
```

Then,

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Tablename ( Column )
 KEY INDEX PK_PriKeyIndex
 ON ftcatalog
 WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
GO
```